# Installing libgl1 to solve OSError: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, python-3.10

I am quite new to linux and ubuntu.
While trying to use the package `femwell` I get the following error :

```
OSError: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked it up and came to the conclusion that I was lacking that file. I tried to install package such as `libgl1` or `libsm6` through

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
```

I also did

```
apt-get update
```

to ensure everything was up to date.

Everything process with no error, however I still get the same error message while running my code with femwell and I don't see any libgl1 file created either in the directory or in the packages of my work environment.

My mentor told me that he manages to make femwell work without installing anything like that, and just by changing a few lines of code in the mesh.py file of femwell, thus I might be wrong with the origin of that error... I tried his solution as well, however it does not work for me and I don't feel confident messing with .py files that are not my own.

What can I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try "sudo apt install mesa-libGLU"
It may not work, but it's worth a shot.